# как подписать apk через React Expo

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Установил **npm install -g expo-cli**

Далее сформировал ключ **expo fetch:android:keystore**

Потом с генерировал Apk **expo build:android -c**
выбрал 2 вариант с подписью записал

```
  Key alias  
  Keystore password
  Key password
```

После размещения в PlayStore пишет: **Подпись загруженного APK недействительна. (Подробнее о подписи…) Описание ошибки: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures.**

Вот такая ошибка. Кто сталкивался с такой темой? нужна помошь

Answer (score 0):

при генерации Signed APK попробуй поставить галочку Signature Version: V1 (Jar Signature)